# How to get the checkpoint location of delta live table?

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables, databricks-autoloader

Suppose you already used checkpoint to update the delta table(external table) with Autoloader. How can I find out its checkpoint location?

I tried running the code below, but it didn't work in my environment.

`SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'databricks_streaming_checkpoint%'`

Answer (score 1):

If you use Delta Live Tables then checkpoints are stored under the storage location specified in the DLT settings.  Each table gets a dedicated directory under `<storage_location/checkpoints/<dlt_table_name>`.

Comment: thank u Alex.
I wanted to know the checkpoint location by just pure code.
for example, delta table file path.

    delta_path = (
        spark.sql(f"DESC FORMATTED {schema_name.lower()}.{data_name.lower()}")
        .filter(col("col_name") == "Location")
        .select("data_type")
    ).collect()[0][0]

Comment: You can query DLT REST API by code to find the storage location. But outside of DLT, the same Delta table could be written by the multiple streams with multiple checkpoints so there is no 1:1 mapping between a table and checkpoint

Answer (score 1):

As [@alex_ott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott) has mentioned in the answer, the checkpoints of your Delta Live Tables are under **Storage location** in **Destination** of **Pipeline settings**.

[image: Pipeline setting / Destination / Storage location]

The Storage location can be set once and at the creation time of a DLT pipeline. In other words, it can be any location but once defined it cannot be changed ever. Regardless whether it was specified explicitly (you) or implicitly (by the system).

[image: Listing of the files and directories under pipelines directory]

[image]

[image]

### Databricks CLI

You can use [Delta Live Tables CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/dlt-cli.html) to access the storage location.

(You could also use the [Delta Live Tables REST API Endpoint](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-api-guide.html) directly)

```
$ databricks pipelines get --pipeline-id 960da65b-c9df-4cb9-9456-1005ffe103a9 | jq '.spec.storage'
"dbfs:/pipelines/960da65b-c9df-4cb9-9456-1005ffe103a9"
```

Comment: I wanted to know the path by code.
because that look cool.
Thank u Jac.

Comment: DLTs are not designed for "coders" IMHO (yet "coders" are not left behind).